# Spring: printing variables in jsp page

Tags: spring, jsp, jakarta-ee

I have been trying out Spring framework and while trying to print java-class attributes in jsp file I have hit a little snag.  While trying to print the date to my page I get nothing.  I know there is a value in the variable as I can see it in the console but on the page there is nothing.  Here is my index.jsp where the value should be shown:

```
    <!-- contains taglibraries -->
<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/jsp/include.jsp" %>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Hello :: Spring Application</title>
    </head>

 <body>
        <h1>Hello - Spring Application</h1>
        <h2>Testing tags</h2>
        <p> <c:out value="If you see this then C-tag works."/> </p>

        <h2>Testing values brought from controller.  One should see a date after "now".</h2>
        <p>Greetings, it is now <c:out value="${now}"/></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is my indexController.java:

```
import java.util.Date;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.Controller;

public class IndexController implements Controller{

    protected Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

    @Override
    public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest hsr, HttpServletResponse hsr1) throws Exception {

        String now = (new Date()).toString();
        logger.info("Returning hello view and " + now);

        return new ModelAndView("WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp" , "now" , now);        

    }  
}
```

Could someone point out what is it I am doing wrong?  Oh and just to clarify: the "include.jsp" contains all my taglibraries so missing taglibrary like this:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
```

Is not a problem as
the first c-tag on the index.jsp works.  The problem is the second c-tag with the variable "now" which refuses to show.

Answer (score 2):

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
```

not including that in your jsp